# Using preg_replace in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I have a CMS content in database. The content contains `'<img src= .............../>'` also. 
I want to retrieve this content using mysql query and show on frontend but with all `'<img src='.........../>'` removed from the content.

How can it be done using query in mysql?

Comment: Why not do this in PHP after you retrieve your content from database?

Comment: Why don't you remove it in PHP? Preferably prior insertion to DB if you will always remove them before displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Once you install [lib_mysqludf_preg](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/) you'll be able to use various regex functions in MySQL. See the docs on that page to find out more about them.

**DISCLAIMER:** I have not used this package and will not guarantee that it won't do anything to the server.