# How to delete anchor tags with Latin text from all posts in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress site in Persian language. It is hacked and there are some advertisement links in every post in site.

I want to remove all of these links from my site. The only pattern I can find in these links is that they contain English characters.

I need a sql command like this:

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'Text to find','text to replace with');
```

But I need it to target anchor links with English characters inside them.
I also need to run it on ACF field, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this in PHP (easier), you can use:

```
preg_replace('/[^\x{0600}–\x{06FF}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{08A0}–\x{08FF}\x{FB50}–\x{FDFF}\x{FE70}–\x{FEFF}\x{10E60}–\x{10E7F}\x{1EE00}—\x{1EEFF}]/u', '', $my_content_from_db);
```

(I assume you're removing everything that's not Farsi and that translates to everything that's not part of the Arabic Unicode character set.)

(I also assume that you're capable of pulling all the posts from the DB, modifying them and writing them back to the DB. If not I can edit this answer with some more information.)

If you must do it in SQL, perhaps try [the library in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505760/using-preg-replace-in-mysql) with the same regex.

Beware that this will remove *everything* that's not in Arabic script. People use words in foreign languages (in your case, possibly ones with non-Arabic characters) within text sometimes. These would get removed.